# Can I PrintToFIle in Access, or possibly spoof the fax driver to create Tifs?

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, fax

I built calculator in Access using a user form. The goal of the calculator is to document the steps taken by the user in solving a problem. It's similar to a high-school student being told to 'show their work'. I need to record a visual representation of the form. A PDF would be perfected, but I can't use PDFs.

I'm limited to file formats that are supported by our imaging server.

I know that the imaging server supports: tif, jpg, bmp and rtf. It might support other formats.

I know that these formats don't work: pdf, gif and png.

I'm an inexperienced coder (less than 6 mos), and I came up with a solution which I suspect is subpar. Occasionally, it seems to just stop working.

Essentially, I copy the form using keybd_event, and paste it into a word document, and save it as a tif file.

Is there a more conventional way of accomplishing this?

Here's my code:

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
      bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12

Public Sub sendToFaf()

    Dim appWord As New Word.Application
    Dim docWord As New Word.Document
    Dim imgWord As InlineShape
    Dim thisForm As Form

    Dim oldPrinter As String
    Dim rnd As Integer
    Dim strRnd As String
    Dim oldWidth As Integer
    Dim oldHeight As Integer

    On Error GoTo ProcessError
    DoCmd.Echo (False)
    DoCmd.Hourglass (True)

    Set appWord = CreateObject("word.application")
    Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Add
    Set thisForm = Screen.ActiveForm

    appWord.Visible = False
    appWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    oldWidth = thisForm.InsideWidth
    oldHeight = thisForm.InsideHeight

    thisForm.InsideWidth = 10800
    thisForm.InsideHeight = 11925

    keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
    DoEvents
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
    DoEvents
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    DoEvents

    thisForm.InsideWidth = oldWidth
    thisForm.InsideHeight = oldHeight


    rnd = Int((10000 - 0 + 1) * Math.rnd + 0)
    strRnd = Format(rnd, "0000")


    With docWord.PageSetup
        .TopMargin = 0
        .BottomMargin = 0
        .LeftMargin = 0
        .RightMargin = 0
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalCenter

    End With
    docWord.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    appWord.Selection.Paste

    Set imgWord = docWord.InlineShapes(docWord.InlineShapes.Count)

    imgWord.Width = InchesToPoints(8.5)

    oldPrinter = appWord.ActivePrinter
    appWord.ActivePrinter = "FAX"

    appWord.PrintOut _
        Background:=False, _
        outputfilename:="c:\a faf\" & thisForm.Name & strRnd & ".tif", _
        PrintToFile:=True

    MsgBox ("File created: 'c:\a faf\" & thisForm.Name & strRnd & ".tif'")
    appWord.ActivePrinter = oldPrinter


ProcessExit:
    Set imgWord = Nothing
    docWord.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    appWord.Quit savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Set docWord = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing
    Set thisForm = Nothing
    DoCmd.Echo (True)
    DoCmd.Hourglass (False)
Exit Sub

ProcessError:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Sub SendToFaf"
    GoTo ProcessExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Rewrote the whole thing. Added my current solution.

Comment: Did DoCmd.PrintOut Access.acForm in the form module not work?

Comment: It doesn't allow you to print to a file. You can trick it by using the fax driver, but my hope is that eventually this will hook into our ftp server. So I would like to avoid all the dialogue screens.

Comment: What I would suggest is printing to a PDF, and then use one of many utilizes to convert the PDF to a tif. In fact some of the free open source libraries like ghost script have this ability.